# Win32 Errror, can't delete files without errors

Tags: python, python-2.7

So my code is basically designed deletes a file if incorrect data is entered. However it doesn't work, surprise surprise.

Here's my code for the deleting segment:

```
except ValueError:
        print("Something went wrong")
        file = open(username + ".txt", "w")
        file.close()
        import os, sys
        os.remove(username + ".txt")
        break
```

and this is the error that I retain:

```
WindowsError: [Error 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'newtext.txt'
```

Any help would be great thanks :D

Comment: Are you using the file from somewhere else? Forgot to close it in a different part of your code or other programs?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have got the text file open in a word processor such as notepad. When running your Python script close the word processor beforehand and your code should work properly. If this does not solve the problem then please give more details and I will try to help you to fix the problem.